# Spring MVC File Upload with multipart data and unit test

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, multifile-uploader

I am using Spring 4 latest, and I generally have no problem writing RESTful controllers.  There is a legacy web-app, which is using java.net.HTTPUrlConnection to do a multi-part upload.  There are 3 pieces of data we are uploading:
1 is a PDF file, and we have the bytes, then the other two pieces of data are just 2 string fields.

First let me show you the Spring REST controller to accept the data:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public @ResponseBody boolean saveData(@RequestPart(value = "field1") String field1, @RequestPart(value = "field2") String field2, @RequestParam(value = "pdfbytes") String pdfbytes)
{
    System.out.println("saveData: field1=" + field1);
    System.out.println("saveData: field2=" + field2);
    System.out.println("saveData: pdfbytes=" + pdfbytes);
    boolean response = true;

    return response;
}
```

The code in front-end, for sending the data using 'java.net.HttpURLConnection'
looks like this:

```
String boundary = MultiPartFormOutputStream.createBoundary();

URL uploadDocumentUrl = new URL(protocol + "://" + host + UPLOAD_EDITED_DOCUMENT);

    HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) MultiPartFormOutputStream.createConnection(uploadDocumentUrl);
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", MultiPartFormOutputStream.getContentType(boundary));
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
    urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    MultiPartFormOutputStream out = new MultiPartFormOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream(), boundary);

    String pdfbytes= getEncodedDocument(pdf);

    out.writeField("field1", field1);
    out.writeField("field2", field2);
    out.writeField("pdfbytes", pdfbytes);

    out.close();
    int responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
    String responseMessage = urlConn.getResponseMessage();
```

"MultiPartFormOutputStream" is a custom object that was created to send data via HttpUrlConnection, it's pretty standard code.  I do trust it at this time.

So, based on how we are sending the data, do I need to change the Controller to do anything different, or does that look ok?

Now here is the code, that I am using to Unit Test that controller:

```
@Test
public void testMockUpload() throws Exception
{
    // Load resource being uploaded
    byte[] pdfbytes = getByteArrayFromFile(FILENAME);

    MockMultipartFile firstFile = new MockMultipartFile("field1", "", "text/plain", "field1 data".getBytes());
    MockMultipartFile secondFile = new MockMultipartFile("field2", "", "text/plain", "field2 data".getBytes());
    MockMultipartFile jsonFile = new MockMultipartFile("pdfbytes", "", "text/plain", pdfbytes);

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload(BASE_URL + "/save").file(firstFile).file(secondFile).file(jsonFile)
    .with(user(USERNAME).roles("role1", "role2")).contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);

    this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

And the error I get back now, is:
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException

which I am looking into.  If I need to make any changes on how I need to create my test, I am very open to that.  Eventually, I will get everything to sync up between the sending code, the receiving controller, and the unit test.

Thanks in advance!  As usual, if there is any other data, or information, I can provide, please let me know.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To upload one file you would define the RequestParam type as org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
            public @ResponseBody boolean saveData(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file)
            {
                return response;
            }
```

For Multiple files I'd try creating a Wrapper form:

```
public class UploadForm{

   private List<MultipartFile> files;
}
```

Bind to this in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public @ResponseBody boolean saveData(@ModelAttribute uploadForm)
    {
        return response;
    }
```

and then use Spring's support for indexed fields to bind to a collection:

Test:

```
MockMultipartFile firstFile = new MockMultipartFile("files[0]", "", "text/plain", "field1 data".getBytes());
    MockMultipartFile secondFile = new MockMultipartFile("files[1]", "", "text/plain", "field2 data".getBytes());
    MockMultipartFile jsonFile = new MockMultipartFile("files[2]", "", "text/plain", pdfbytes);
```

Client:

```
out.writeField("files[0]", file1Bytes);
out.writeField("files[1]", file2Bytes);
...
```